# Embedding ajax into js library

Tags: ajax, javascript

I have a JS library and I would like to add Ajax in it like jQuery and ProtoypeJS. Please can you give me the code used in jQuery and ProtoypeJS.

Comment: Why both? And no, we cannot give you them. Just look them up in their well-documented sources: https://github.com/jquery/jquery and https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype

Comment: I have looked at that but I don't know where the other ajax parts come from.

Comment: Now, that's no ajax part. jQuery ajax for example utilizes `extend`, its `Deferred` object and `$.Callbacks`, and HTML / JSON parser. You will find such helper functions somewhere in the lib, just as you found `ajax`.

Comment: I said ajax par t by accident I meant object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what to do. After having a quick look at http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript/ I think I can download the source and tweak it to work. :)